# If I have two 18650 Li-ion batteries with different capacities, can I charge them using the same circuit?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have several 18650 Li-Ion batteries, many with different capacities. Can I charge them with the same charging circuit (5 to 3.7 V 1 A buck converter)? Can I put them in parallel and use the same step up circuit to make a 5 V USB bank?

Comment: Have you done any research on this yet?

Comment: I have tried, but I can't really find anything on this. Most of the time its just about one type of battery, and when it isn't, its about different chemestries, or ages of batterys.

Comment: You shouldn't be using just a buck converter to charge Li-Ion batteries, and 3.7V 'nominal' batteries are seldom (if ever) charged at 3.7V (4.1V or so would be more common). Are you using a charge controller?

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to buy a 18650 charger off of ebay or something

Comment: Should be fine if you can balance their voltages first.

Comment: That would mean charging each battery individually up to 3.75 to 4 volts right?

Comment: They need to be the same voltage range, but otherwise, put simply, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to charge each cell individually, then it should be fine, provided that the charger doesn't exceed max charging current for the smaller cell. But if you mean to make a battery out of two different cell in parallel, and charge-discharge them as a battery, then the following apply:

One should **never** charge different Li-Ion batteries in parallel. It is true even if the cells are of the same rating, but their charge-discharge characterics do not match to high (1-2%) degree. Charging cells in parallel is unacceptable for three reasons:

1. Li-Ion cells with different capacity will take different time because a smaller-capacity cell will/might be charged first, and then will be overexposed to charging voltage (while the bigger cell still gets the charge). This will result in "overcharging" of the weaker cell, it will grow some bad chemistry inside, its capacity will fall more, and it will die being bloated or worse.
2. On discharge cycle the process is also bad - weaker (less capacity) cell might be depleted first, and fall into "overdischarged" state, with similar bad implication for internal chemistry.
3. On charge, a stronger cell with less internal impedance might take more current than the cell design can afford, which can lead to "fast venting including fire".

In short, it is a very bad idea to make a battery from different Li-Ion cells in parallel without either perfect matching, or using some electronics to manage each cell individually.

Comment: If they are in parallel, the voltage across must be the same. So, for #1: how would the smaller capacity cell be charged sooner? During charging, 3.5V is 3.5V. One cell cannot reach a higher level than another. #2: same as #1. How can either be more depleted, percentage wise? Perhaps only if the state of health had changed significantly. #3: Agreed, though it can be accounted for.

Comment: @Bort, Li-Ion chemistry gets its predominant charge during constant-current phase. The voltage is creeping up slowly during the process. When the internal chemistry gets charged to certain degree, the cell starts to consume less and less current, which is a precursor to end the charge. First, no one can guess how the input current will be split between two cells (#3), then a smaller cell will/might charge faster, its current will drop, while the other is still charging (#1) and consuming current (so the charger won't stop) thus overexposing the smaller cell.

Comment: It sounds like the only issue is overcurrent (and not voltage), would you agree? If, say, the paralleled cells are charged by a 1A charger, and 1A is not above the max for any individual cell, then there is no issue with current, yes? For discharge, I am assuming the draw is also managed to be less than any particular cell's max. No offense, but I am still doubting your #1 and #2. I have been told be colleges in the Li-ion field that there are battery packs used in consumer products, such as macbooks, that actually use batteries in parallel. (I have to verify that.)

Comment: @Bort, the voltage was never an issue, assuming identical cell chemistries. In almost all cases (before proliferation of small tablets and smartphones) all laptop batteries were made in mixed configuration, 2P or 3P (in parallel), and 3S (11.1V). But all cells in the parallel sections are carefully selected/matched by manufacturers with nearly identical characteristics.

Comment: @Bort, the "overcurrent" is only one concern. The major issue is with 
"overcharge". It is not about too much current, but rather "too little current", when a cell is full and consumes no more current, but is still exposed to voltage. This  causes so-called "overcharge" condition, which leads to degradation of almost all elements, lithium  depositions in metal form, degradation of electrode surfaces, membrane damages, etc. Please examine some scholar articles on the subject, as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921510714002657

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "...that actually use batteries of different capacity in parallel". Anyway, you are saying that being exposed to voltage when fully charged is bad, yes, I'm not arguing that. That's why I asked about it being a voltage issue (I wouldn't call it a current issue). If the cells are in parallel, then they will always be at the same voltage, and I'm not sure how one will overcharge before another, outside of the standard tolerance differences and SoH.

Comment: This answer is flat out wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Ale's answer to this is incorrect.**

> Li-Ion cells with different capacity will take different time because a smaller-capacity cell will/might be charged first, and then will be overexposed to charging voltage (while the bigger cell still gets the charge). This will result in "overcharging" of the weaker cell, it will grow some bad chemistry inside, its capacity will fall more, and it will die being bloated or worse.

If one cell were to be a higher voltage than another, current would flow from that cell to the lower cell. The impedance of the cells is quite low so the voltages are effectively locked together. Therefore overcharging a cell is not a risk.

Discharging works the same way. At reasonable rates of discharge like 1C, the cell voltages will continue to be locked together. You can't over-discharge a cell, because if that were to happen current would start flowing *into* it from the other cells. In practice it will never even get into this state.

At extremely high rates of discharge (we're talking 10's of amps here), the ESR mismatch of the batteries may cause them to go out of balance. If at any time the load is removed though, the batteries will start to re-balance as current flows from the high cell to the low cell. This is only really relevant in RC and similar high stress applications where a pack might be discharged in under 2 minutes.

> On charge, a stronger cell with less internal impedance might take
>   more current than the cell design can afford, which can lead to "fast
>   venting including fire".

If a cell has less impedance and charges faster it's voltage will go up infinitesimally, this will cause it to take less current. At low rates of charge, the cells will naturally distribute current in proportion to their capacity. One caveat is that if a wire breaks, the current will be redistributed to the other cells, potentially exceeding their charging limits.

Disclaimer: the preceding only applies to single cells with varying capacity in parallel. With series cells its more complicated.

Lipos *can* be dangerous. This is all theoretical so please take it with a grain of salt. I'm posting it anyway because Ale's answer is misinformative, even if it is well intentioned.

Comment: "so the voltages are effectively locked together. Therefore overcharging a cell is not  risk." -  you probably need to check with other sources for the meaning of "overcharging of Li-Ion cell". Two kinds of overcharge are usually considered, "overcharge" due to too high charging current (and associated thermal effects), and degradation of electrolyte due to prolonged exposure to charging voltage (constant voltage!!!). In no case people consider overcharge as "overvoltage", Please start with layman articles such as https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Comment: However, I might agree with your point about overdischarging. And my third point about uneven current distribution might be questionable, the current split depends on particularities of cell design (high-discharge lower capacity cell may have lower ESR and consume higher charge). However, my first point about overcharging (in the sense of overexposing a cell to charging voltage) is absolutely valid.  Please read comments to my answer.

Comment: During proper charging a lipo will not be exposed to voltages in excess of the full cell voltage. A fully charged cell has no way to "know" the charger is even there, since no current will flow into it, just as none would flow if there was an open circuit.

Comment: "A fully charged cell has no way to "know" the charger is even there"  - not true. Read the literature.  From cited Battery University: *Li-ion cannot absorb overcharge. When fully charged, the charge current must be cut off. A continuous trickle charge would cause plating of metallic lithium and compromise safety.*

Comment: If the battery cell is 4.2v and the charger output is also 4.2v there will be no trickling of anything. No current whatsoever will flow.

Comment: "No current whatsoever will flow" - that is the problem. The problem seems to be not in current flow, but in lack thereof. According to academic literature, degradation of electrodes goes faster when Li-Ion cell is exposed to terminal voltage. Again: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921510714002657 Ask yuorself differently, If you could safely keep a Li-ion cell under charging voltage all times, why would every charger IC manufacturer bother to disconnect cells when charging current drops below 10% threshold?.

Comment: Just throwing my hat in the ring here for those to view this later. Ale's answer is unequivocally wrong, and Drew's is right. The other things to consider are the thermals. In high C rate applications, the lower impedance cells will generate more heat as they do more work.

Comment: @Nino, electrochemical elements generate heat only on parasitic internal impedance. So lower impedance will generate LESS heat. And you've been very self-critical in your profile, this is the one thinkg where you are correct. You and Drew are very confused. Which part of the statement that "degradation of electrolyte due to prolonged exposure to charging voltage" you are objecting to?

Comment: Alex, imagine if you tried to create a test stand for this. You connect a 6Ah, and 100mAh 1s in parallel and begin charging them at 6.1A. Now lets say you want to demonstrate that the 100mAh battery is being overcharged. How would you do that? You would measure the voltage, and because it's in parallel with the larger battery, it will be the same voltage. Good luck "overcharging" the 100mAh battery without getting it over 4.2v. Or do you think the voltage of the smaller battery will rise once it's disconnected from the circuit?

Comment: @Ale..chenski, Drew is still right, sorry. Regarding the heating, you are wrong. Two cells charged to the same voltage but with differing impedances will supply different currents. The lower impedance cell will supply more current, and heating goes with current squared. 

If you had two 4.2V cells in parallel with another, and cell A had 1 Ohm impedance and cell B had 2 Ohm impedance, and you connected a 3A load, cell A would instantly do 2A and cell B would do 1A. Cell A would be dissipating 4W while cell B would be dissipating 2W.

Comment: This is all to first order of course. A lower impedance cell would probably have less capacity, so there would be higher order effects.

Comment: @Nino and Drew, I have to ask again: which part of "prolonged exposure to charging voltage" is unclear?

Comment: @Ale..chenski Nothing will happen to the electrolyte if no current is flowing into the battery. If the cell is at 4.2 (fully charged), and the charger is supplying 4.2V(max), then there is no differential and no current will flow. I think you may be confused with lead acid charging, where the charger floats the cell at a higher than the nominal cell voltage. Lipo's don't work that way. It is true that keeping a lipo fully charged will degrade it chemically over months or years (raising the ESR), but that has nothing to do with parallel charging.

Comment: Drew: From "Battery University", an explicit statement: "When fully charged, the charge current must be cut off. A continuous trickle charge would cause plating of metallic lithium and compromise safety. To minimize stress, keep the lithium-ion battery at the peak cut-off as short as possible." Please stop exposing your ignorance. Reaching full "float voltage" (4.2 V or else) does not constitute "full charge". To appreciate complexity of Li-Ion, please learn about SEI, intercalation, dendrites, plating, outgassing, and other concepts of solid-state chemistry and diffusion processes in general.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, you most recent comment is correct in theory, but it seems you lack understanding in practice.

In the real world, chargers charge to the float voltage, and they sit there. Smarter products charge to some fraction of SOC and then stop to prolong life, but most don't. These chargers that charge to the float voltage would damage a cell regardless of whether or not there is another chemistry in parallel.

Comment: Your other misunderstanding in practicality is that cell impedances are so wildly different that one would sit at the float voltage for dangerous amounts of time while the higher capacity cell is still charging. Realistically, the capacity cell may have an impedance of 60mOhm and the power cell may have an impedance of 20mOhm. Lets say you were charging at 4A across both cells. Initially, the power cell would charge with 3A, but as it would charge more quickly, it's current would quickly drop, and eventually equalize proportionally to it's capacity vs the other.

Comment: @Nino, you are talking about primary effects. My post was about long-term battery functionality. The effects I describe are of second order. If you plan to charge your parallel battery 20-30 times, that is fine. But if you expect the parallel-connected cells to last 1000s of cycles, forget it. And it sound really funny when a sophomore student is schooling a 70+ PhD about misunderstanding of practicalities. Try to digest at least 5% of the article I posted, maybe it will help. If not, consider changing profession.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Haha if I was still a young sophomore student, I would probably still be vain enough to buy a couple cells and prove this to you. But since I am not, I will leave that exercise to you. You can try the LG MJ1 as your capacity cell and LG HD2 as your power cell. You can buy any Chinese battery charger for $5. Otherwise, enjoy the darkness.

Comment: To be clear though, the question asked about cell capacity (not ESR) and using a 1A charger, which in a multiple cell configuration would be a very low C rate.

ESR mismatch will degrade long term cycle life in high C-rate applications with LFP cells, but this application is not high C-rate, and this assumes an ESR mismatch, and LFP cells.